# Add constraints to additionalProperties in openapi

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm trying to add a maxLength constraint to the 'value' part of a Map<String, String> that I generate from the following yaml:

```
MyMap:
  type: object
  additionalProperties:
    type: string
```

I would have expected to be able to do something like this:

```
MyMap:
  type: object
  additionalProperties:
    type: string
    maxLength: 30
```

And have it generate the following code:

```
Map<String, @Size(max = 30)String>
```

However it does not add the '@Size()' to the generated java model. Is it possible to add this type of length constraint to the value part of the Map in some way?

I am already using this in an array where it works perfectly:

```
read:
  type: array
  items:
    type: string
    maxLength: 30
```

This generates the javacode:

```
read(List<@Size(max = 30)String> read)
```

Comment: What are you expecting to be the change in the java model? There's no difference in Java between a string and a string restricted to 30 characters. They're both just strings.

Comment: I would expect something similar to Map<String, @Size(max = 30)String> to be generated so I have Spring do the validation. I am using this elsewhere in my code where it working just fine. I just can't get it to work on the map.

Comment: sounds like a bug when processing additionalProperties schema from whatever tool you're using